# Wrap the key-value pairs with double quotes in Json String in java

Tags: java, spring

To make it into a valid JSON

```
"{containerId:81,params:[{parameterName:vinay,valueInDesignMode:where actor_id<50,valueInRunMode:where actor_id<100},{parameterName:name,valueInDesignMode:where actor < =10,valueInRunMode:},{parameterName:nameID,valueInDesignMode:,valueInRunMode:}]}"
```

Expected output

```
{"containerId":81,"params":[{"parameterName":"vinay","valueInDesignMode":"where actor_id<50","valueInRunMode":"where actor_id<100","containerId":81},{"parameterName":"name","valueInDesignMode":"where actor < =10","valueInRunMode":""},{"parameterName":"nameID","valueInDesignMode":"","valueInRunMode":""}]}
```

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  1) In general you can't add a double to a JSON string.  2) Convert *what( to valid JSON?  3) The Java string literal in the question is not valid JSON. There are many possible ways to massage it into JSON, but we have no idea which will meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputJson = "{containerId:81,params:[{parameterName:vinay,valueInDesignMode:where actor_id<50,valueInRunMode:where actor_id<100},{parameterName:name,valueInDesignMode:where actor < =10,valueInRunMode:},{parameterName:nameID,valueInDesignMode:,valueInRunMode:}]}";

    String outputJson =
            inputJson
                    .replace(" ", "")
                    .replaceAll("([\\w]+):", "\"$1\":")
                    .replaceAll(":([\\w|<|=]+)", ": \"$1\"")
                    .replaceAll("\"([\\d]+)\"", "$1")
                    .replace(":}", ": \"\"}")
                    .replace(":]", ": \"\"]")
                    .replace(":,", ": \"\",");        

    System.out.println(outputJson);
}
```

Although this code gives your desired result but you can find better solutions.

Comment: unable to replace the missing values with double-quotes. For the remaining key-value pairs it's working fine.

Comment: {"containerId": 81,"params":[{"parameterName": "param46","valueInDesignMode": "limit21","valueInRunMode":}]}

Answer (score 0):

To convert the above Object to JSON you need to make the key and value as a string like the below and later you can parse the JSON to evaluate the conditional statements.

```
{
"containerId":81,
"params":[
    {
        "parameterName":"vinay",
        "valueInDesignMode":"where actor_id<50",
        "valueInRunMode":"where actor_id<100"
    },
    {
        "parameterName":"name",
        "valueInDesignMode":"where actor < =10",
        "valueInRunMode":null
    },
    {
        "parameterName":"nameID",
        "valueInDesignMode": null,
        "valueInRunMode":null
    }
]}
```

Comment: How can we add if the values are missing ??

Comment: we can pass null for that